# regular expression to reverse the order of two unknown words separated by a comma

Tags: regex

I am trying to use ReNamer regular expressions to reverse folder names that use author names. They are set up as "LastName, FirstName" and I need to change them to "FirstName LastName" minus the comma. In ReNamer regular expressions usage is set up as Expression on one line & Replace on the second. I assume in this case Input then Output. I've tried several solutions from here but could not get anything to work at all. The help file states that it uses Delphi for this. I barely understand the extreme basics of regex so any and all help is much appreciated.

Comment: regex `([^,]*), *(.*)`, replace `\2 \1`

Comment: There's no obvious delphi here. This is renamer whatever that is. Doesn't really feel like a programming question. what you need to do is read the docs of your program and work out what regex flavour is in use.

Comment: According file & folder renaming program, ReNamer, regex is the only option of several choices that will do what I need. I tried what you just suggested... "Expression: ([^,]*), *(.*) then Replace: \2 \1. he result changed "Duncan, Dave" to "2 1".

Comment: This isn't a programming question. You've posted on the wrong site. You need http://superuser.com. Or the support for your program.

Comment: @RogerParker Please [edit] your question to include what you've tried already.

Answer (score 0):

[ReNamer's find-and-replace supports backreferences.](http://www.den4b.com/wiki/ReNamer:Regular_Expressions#Backreferences) This means you can match `LastName, FirstName` with:

```
(.+),\s*(.+)

(.+)          LastName as subexpression 1
    ,\s*      delimiter between LastName and FirstName, comma followed by any amount of whitespace
        (.+)  FirstName as subexpression 2
```

and spit out `FirstName LastName` with this replace string:

```
$2 $1

$2     backreference to subexpr 2, which is FirstName
   $1  backreference to subexpr 1, which is LastName
```

This and similar constructs will work on any find-and-replace that supports regex with backreferences, not just ReNamer.

---

You can make `(.+),\s*(.+)` fit different use cases with slight modifications. For instance, to disallow commas in LastName, you can make the LastName subexpression match `[^,]+` instead of `.+`:

```
([^,]+),\s*(.+)

 [^,]            anything but comma
```

Or to make sure the delimiter is always a comma followed by whitespace:

```
(.+),\s+(.+)

     \s+      one or more whitespace characters (\s* accepts zero or more)
```

Or to allow empty names:

```
(.*),\s*(.*)
```